# Passing Route Parameter to Mongoose Query Express

Tags: node.js

Basically I'm trying to find a way in which to find a way to plug `req.params.name` into a `find()` query.

I have tried:

Trying to pass through my `req.params` variable in my `find()` object parameter `Card.find({cardName: req.params.name}, callback)` and any other possible variance of that.

I've tried a static method for `findByName` in which I just did `Card.findByName(req.params.name, callback);`

When I do `console.lo(req.params.name)` it returns the name of the card; however, when I got to show.ejs I do `console.log(cardstatsok.cardName)` it comes back undefined.

I've searched here on Stack Overflow, I've checked my Udemy message board, and I've tried finding any tutorial on passing route parameters to a find query, and alas, nothing.

Here's my code:

My schema and model:

```
var cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cardName: String,
    id: Number,
    cardSet: String,
    image: String,
    ability: String
});

var Card = mongoose.model("Card", cardSchema);
```

My route for my single card page:

```
app.get("/cards/:name", function(req, res) {
    Card.find({"cardName":req.params.name}, function(err, cardInfo){
       if(err){
           res.redirect("/cards");
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           res.render("show", {cardstatsok: cardInfo});
       }
    });
});
```

When I do `console.log(cardInfo)` it returns many objects since I used "Forest" and the copy of the Magic: The Gathering card Forest has been printed many times.  Here's one, though:

```
  { _id: 5a85bb554c8fff0c04f15b8e,
    cardName: 'Forest',
    id: 243461,
    cardSet: 'Duel Decks: Knights vs. Dragons',
    image: 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=243461&type=card',
    __v: 0 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: `console.log(cardInfo)` brings back a whole bunch of objects (because this card has more than one copy).

Comment: Check edit for console.log

Comment: cardstatsok is an array so `console.log(cardstatsok.cardName)` won't work. Try `console.log(cardstatsok[0].cardName)` instead for the first card or `console.log(cardstatsok)` for everything. If you want to print all the card names you have to loop over the array.

Comment: Oh, wow, yeah.  I forgot that since there are multiple forests I'll need to find my specific one.

Comment: Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` returns an array which means `cardstatsok` is an array.

So `console.log(cardstatsok.cardName)` won't work. Use `console.log(cardstatsok[0].cardName)` instead for the first card or `console.log(cardstatsok)` for everything. If you want to print all the card names you have to loop over the array.

To find only one card you can use `findOne()` instead.